# What kind of numbers should be used for boosting at indexing time in ElasticSearch?

Tags: boost, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

In my web project, I use Django and elasticsearch_dsl. This is a sample code for indexing registered users:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, ...

class UserDocType(DocType):
    pk = Long()
    fullname = String(analyzer='standard', boost=5, fields={'raw': String(index='not_analyzed')})
    description = String(analyzer='german', boost=0.5)
    keywords = String(analyzer='german', boost=9)
    boost_text_1 = String(analyzer='german', boost=18)
    boost_text_2 = String(analyzer='german', boost=27)
    boost_text_3 = String(analyzer='german', boost=36)
```

In some examples, I see the boost values between 0 and 1, but in some examples I see 30, 40 or more. Which is true way for it? Is it about boost_mode or score_mode?